# How to check if a user is also an administrator?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I  have a ClickOnce application and on startup I want to check if the user is an administrator.

When starting the application, I'm logged in as myself, and my user is member of the `Administrators` group. `UAC` is also turned off.

My first attempt was the following:

```
var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
var admin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

The above didn't work. Going through all built-in roles, only `WindowsBuiltInRole.User` returns `true`. So the second attempt was the following:

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
foreach (var role in identity.Groups)
{
    if (role.IsValidTargetType(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
    {
        var sid = role.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)) as SecurityIdentifier;
        if (sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid) || sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid) )
        {
            admin = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This second attempt didn't work either. `admin` stays `false`.

To further test the above, I created a new user and added him only to the `Administrators` group. He is not in the `Users` group. Starting the app as this new user will still return `false`.

The only time the above code will return `true`, ie. the user is an administrator, is when I log in and start the app and the pre-installed `Administrator` user account.

As I have `UAC` turned off I shouldn't be dealing with split tokens.

Is the problem related to the application being a ClickOnce app?

Is there a way (that actually works) which will return whether the user is actually an adminisatrator (note: the user can be part of the `Domain Admins` group but not a local admin)?

Comment: Check if this method works for you : https://ayende.com/blog/158401/are-you-an-administrator

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get `AuthenticationException` and `FileNotFoundException`.